# 401 Unauthorized or in the response "Could not authenticate you" with error 32 in Twitter at user request

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, winjs

I try to build an Windows 8 app where I'll integrate Twitter. So there is no callback URL.
After long search I've made it to obtain user token and secret. Now I try to get users timeline. But I always get 401 Unauthorized or in the response "Could not authenticate you" with error 32. I've used the OAuth Tool to generate Authorization header and Signature base string to compare it with the values I send. They looks pretty similar to me, except the nonce.

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fhome_timeline.json&oauth_consumer_key%3DGszx6r0cSieo3OwyH3SA%26oauth_nonce%3D4387f13969df533a0b0a294d9884506b%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1371117616%26oauth_token%3D1470508532-5JPWuH66asacc45qGkKKYuP50QEPOA55VrXfV9o%26oauth_version%3D1.0

GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fhome_timeline.json&oauth_consumer_key%3DGszx6r0cSieo3OwyH3SA%26oauth_nonce%3D190930700%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1371117905%26oauth_token%3D1470508532-5JPWuH66asacc45qGkKKYuP50QEPOA55VrXfV9o%26oauth_version%3D1.0

Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="Gszx6r0cSieo3OwyH3SA", oauth_nonce="4387f13969df533a0b0a294d9884506b", oauth_signature="QQOO4aUJx9%2FNKYidvuPx%2Fv7YzNg%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1371117616", oauth_token="1470508532-5JPWuH66asacc45qGkKKYuP50QEPOA55VrXfV9o", oauth_version="1.0"

Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="Gszx6r0cSieo3OwyH3SA", oauth_nonce="701369537", oauth_signature="VKjaVFHL%2FgtCRCASW5qdQtE%2BiJA%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1371118662", oauth_token="1470508532-5JPWuH66asacc45qGkKKYuP50QEPOA55VrXfV9o", oauth_version="1.0"
```

First codes are from OAuth Tool, second are my codes.

Thanks Marlowe

Comment: shouldn't the `oauth_nonce` in the URL and the auth header match?  Yours do not - URL has `190930700` where the auth header has `701369537`.

Comment: Sorry my example was bad.
"GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2F&oauth_consumer_key%3DGszx6r0cSieo3Ow‌​yH3SA%26oauth_nonce%3D598839869%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_time‌​stamp%3D1371126265%26oauth_token%3D1408527230-WDl609FrIKuURzz5xWk2zZmZstO5OeD2PkO‌​4iEi%26oauth_version%3D1.0" Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="Gszx6r0cSieo3OwyH3SA", oauth_nonce="598839869", oauth_signature="dT21EINyNsW9KgtlSbKVb7U3HwQ%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1371126265", oauth_token="1408527230-WDl609FrIKuURzz5xWk2zZmZstO5OeD2PkO4iEi", oauth_version="1.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was one single character to much. After I've found them, it's working. By the way: nonce works also with the small version I've used in the example.